# laravel collection group by then order by

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collections, sql-order-by

maybe trivial but i'm stuck on this.

```
$questions = FaqQuestion::with('category')->get()->groupBy('faq_categories_id')->sortBy('sortorder');
```

The result is grouped by faq_categories_id, and sorted by FaqQuestion id it seems.  I want to orderBy the 'sortorder' field ASC from FaqQuestion, the same column name exists in category.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks

edit:

$questions returns a collection:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1309 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1154 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => App\FaqQuestion {#1385 ▼
          +table: "faq_questions"
          #dates: array:4 [▶]
          #fillable: array:6 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:10 [▶]
          #original: array:10 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #classCastCache: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: array:1 [▶]
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #forceDeleting: false
        }
        1 => App\FaqQuestion {#1387 ▶}
        2 => App\FaqQuestion {#1388 ▶}
      ]
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#430 ▶}
    3 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#431 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: why not group & sort data before get()?

`FaqQuestion::with('category')->groupBy('faq_categories_id')->orderBy('sortorder')->get();`

Comment: groupBy doesn't work on collections. your suggestion returns an error

Comment: `FaqQuestion` is a collection?

Comment: Yes, i updated the question with the collection, thanks @user3402600

Comment: Why can’t you apply group by and order by on the eloquent model? From your code I can see that  App\FaqQuestion is a model... Even though that can be done using collection, you will run into memory issues should your data set grow.